# From list of tuples, find tuple with max value for a certain index , where the rest of the tuple is the same

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, filtering

From a list of tuples, I want to identify the tuples, which hav the maximum value for tuple[2] (i.e. the third value), but the same values otherwise

i.e. from

```
searchlist = [(a,b,2),(a,b,3),(a,b,4),(a,b,5),(x,y,2),(x,y,4)]
```

I want to find

```
result = [(a,b,5),(x,y,4)]
```

Comment: Where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: there is no code yet, because I dont really know where to start. just sorting with lambda or itemgetter will not respect the requirement that I need the max for tuple[2] for each sublist of tuples that have the same tuple[0],tuple[1] combination

Comment: @Bakuriu , yes I saw it now. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might first [sort](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) your values, then you will be able to use [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group values with the same two first elements. Finally, [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) can retrieve the maximum value for each.

```
from itertools import groupby

a, b, x, y = "a", "b", "x", "y"
searchlist = [(a,b,2),(a,b,3),(a,b,4),(a,b,5),(x,y,2),(x,y,4)]

searchlist.sort()
grouped = groupby(searchlist, key=lambda v: (v[0], v[1]))
maximums = [max(groups) for value, groups in grouped]

print(maximums)
# [("a", "b", 5), ("x", "y", 4)]
```

Comment: Don't forget from `itertools import groupby` (downvote is not mine)

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH.Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby

searchlist = [('a','b',2),('a','b',3),('a','b',4),('a','b',5),('x','y',2),('x','y',4)]
result = [max(v, key = lambda x: x[2]) for g, v in groupby(sorted(searchlist), key = lambda x: x[:2])]
```

Comment: you are right, I've corrected the solution

Answer (score 0):

[Python sorting how to](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) tells feature for of sorting in python.
Use `reverse=True` as you need in in decreasing order.

```
In [62]: sorted(searchlist, key=lambda a: (a[2], a[1], a[0]), reverse=True)
Out[62]: 
[('a', 'b', 5),
 ('x', 'y', 4),
 ('a', 'b', 4),
 ('a', 'b', 3),
 ('x', 'y', 2),
 ('a', 'b', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've used in the past to accomplish something similar

```
def layered_sort(iterable, indices_to_sort_by, include_duplicates=True):
    # indices_to_sort_by is a list of indices to sort by
    result = []
    for item in iterable:
        index = find_place(item, result, indices_to_sort_by, include_duplicates)
        if index is not None:
            result.insert(index, item)
    return result


def find_place(item, result, indices, include_duplicates=True):
    # in case result is empty
    # and n never gets initialized
    t_len = len(result)
    top = t_len
    bottom = 0
    n = 0
    while top>bottom:
        n = (top+bottom)/2
        sorted_item = result[n]
        for index in indices:
            ob1 = item[index]
            ob2 = sorted_item[index]
            # if they are equal, sort
            # by next highest priority
            if ob1 != ob2:
                if sorted([ob1, ob2]) == [ob1, ob2]:
                    # ob1 belongs in front of ob2
                    top = n
                else:
                    n += 1
                    bottom = n
                # move on to next place in result
                break
        # identical match, insert behind
        else:
            if include_duplicates:
                return n
            else:
                return
    return n
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do with looping over the search list list of tuple and check for the value the third element as well as put first two elements as dict keys like below:

```
val = 0
for a, b, value in searchlist:
   key = "%s-%s" %(a,b)
   if value > val and key in dict_val:
     elem = (a, b, value)
   dict_val[key] = elem

print dict_val.values()
```